# Problems with Android Studios - Flutter (Mac Catalina)

Tags: macos, android-studio

- Mac: Catalina 10.15.7
- Android Studios: 4.1.0
- Flutter: 1.22

I installed Flutter and Android studios, everything with the installation works just fine.

But when I try and run the standard flutter app I face a screen saying:

"AVD Manager"
Unable to locate adb

When the simulator finally runs it always shows "System UI isn't responding".

I've googled and YouTubed the problem and one thing that shows up is the "Emulated Performance" tab under the Tools -> AVD.
Mine is (what I think is correct) set to Graphics: Hardware.

Apart from that I also got the following error "adb: error: failed to get feature set: device 'emulator-5554' not found
Error launching application on sdk gphone x86 arm"

The last message appears when I clicked on "fix it" in "KOTLIN_BUNDLED is undefined. **Fix it**"

Edit:

I got the Android simulator to work, but not the iOS-one.
I start it up and then I try and start my app, the console prints out the following:

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (2nd generation) in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           67.9s
Waiting for iPhone SE (2nd generation) to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54165/D09Fs10d3sA=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone SE (2nd generation)...

This occurs with all different iPhone simulators and the screen goes white, no matter how long time it gets to load.

[KOTLIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThPlW.jpg)

[ADB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi5W5.png)

[System UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szW6f.png)

Comment: 1) What does [flutter doctor](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#run-flutter-doctor) say. 2) Can you create and run a "Hello World" native Java/Kotlin app from Android Studio?

Comment: 1. Flutter Doctor gives me all good, no issues there.
2. I do get the same "System UI isn't responding", but the app starts in the background and works.

Comment: I got the android simulator to work, I had to update the Kotlin app and it works perfectly.
But regarding the iOS simulator: I've started it through Xcode and it works fine, but as soon as I start the flutter app I get "Syncing files to device iPhone 11 Pro..." and it stays there.
It never loads on completely to my iOS simulator.
I do get so I can start the app from the home screen, but it's blank.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to download an Android virtual device by any chance? I had a similar problem and what I did was I just reinstalled Flutter. But that is something you should do when all of the above options aren't working.